# Create dummies from column with multiple values in dask

Tags: dask

My question is similar to this thread [Create dummies from column with multiple values in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889588/create-dummies-from-column-with-multiple-values-in-pandas)

Objective: I would like to produce similar result below but using dask

In Pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'fruit': ['Banana, , Apple, Dragon Fruit,,,', 'Kiwi,', 'Lemon, Apple, Banana', ',']})
df['fruit'].str.get_dummies(sep=',')
```

Which will output the following:

```
          Apple  Banana Dragon Fruit    Banana  Kiwi    Lemon
0     1      1        0            1         1     0        0
1     0      0        0            0         0     1        0
2     0      1        1            0         0     0        1
3     0      0        0            0         0     0        0
```

get_dummies() above is of type <pandas.core.strings.StringMethods>

Now the problem is there is no get_dummies() for dask equivalent <dask.dataframe.accessor.StringAccessor>

How can I solve my problem using dask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is not possible in dask as we wouldn't know the output columns before hand. See https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/4403.

Answer (score 0):

This *is* possible @Santosh_Kumar_Janumahanthi.

And, @anwari there *is* a [`.get_dummies` dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.reshape.get_dummies.html) equivalent.

Dask is lazy in its computations. Therefore, dask doesn't know all the unique values within a column until after computation.  Therefore, dask requires columns to be [categorized](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe-categoricals.html) before one-hot encoding (i.e. [`dd.get_dummies`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.reshape.get_dummies.html)).

`str.split` must execute first, then `.get_dummies` can execute upon the new columns, then the newly encoded columns can join the original DF.

This is how I solved the problem:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'fruit': ['Banana, , Apple, Dragon Fruit,,,', 'Kiwi,', 'Lemon, Apple, Banana', ',']})
df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)  # I made sure to choose a partition count lower than my row number.

col_name_to_split = 'fruit'

def split_col(df: pd.DataFrame, col: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    tmp_df = df[col].str.split(',', expand=True)
    df = df.drop(columns=[col])
    tmp_df.columns = [f'{col}__{x}' for x in tmp_df.columns]  # dunderscore to distinguish when dropping later and not mix with encoded integers.
    anticipated_splits = 7  # Dask will not know how many splits will result from mapping this function (dask can only see the values within the current partition it is iterating over), so you must inform Dask in advance (similar to supplying `meta`).
    for col1 in [f'{col}__{num}' for num in range(anticipated_splits)]:
        tmp_df[col1] = tmp_df.get(col1, float('nan'))  # Fill in with blank if this partition happens not to have all the newly split columns
    df = df.join(tmp_df)
    return df

df = df.map_partitions(split_col, col_name_to_split)


split_cols = [col for col in df.columns if f"{col_name_to_split}__" in col]
df = df.categorize(split_cols)  # This will trigger all queued computations so that dask will know how many dummy columns to make.
tmp_dfs = {}
for col in split_cols:
    tmp_df = dd.get_dummies(df[col], prefix=col_name_to_split)
    tmp_df = tmp_df.map(lambda v: float('nan') if not v else v)  # 
        # So that `.combine_first` doesn't overwrite existing `True`s with incoming `False`s.
        # Caveat: the one hot columns render as `1.0` and as `True` in different columns. Dunno why. But these values are treated as equivalent
    df = df.combine_first(tmp_df)
    tmp_dfs[col] = tmp_df
df = df.drop(columns=split_cols)
```

```
  fruit_ fruit_  fruit_ Apple fruit_ Banana fruit_ Dragon Fruit fruit_Banana  \
0   True    True         True           NaN                True         True   
1   True     NaN          NaN           NaN                 NaN          NaN   
2    NaN     NaN         True          True                 NaN          NaN   
3   True     NaN          NaN           NaN                 NaN          NaN   

  fruit_Kiwi fruit_Lemon  
0        NaN         NaN  
1       True         NaN  
2        NaN        True  
3        NaN         NaN
```

(This is nearly identical to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77099329/4420657))