# Dummy/One Hot Encoding of Comma Separated column in Dask

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, dask

I have a column in a `dask` data frame that contains comma separated lists of different categories. I'm looking to replicate the functionality of `sklearn`'s MultiLabelBinarizer or the `pandas` function `pd.get_dummies(',')` exactly as this thread describes: [Create dummies from column with multiple values in dask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64237300/create-dummies-from-column-with-multiple-values-in-dask)

Is there absolutely no way to do this as the one answer there states? Is there a way to implement this if I got a list of all of the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the list of all classes are known, then it's an easy task for `dask`:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

df = pd.DataFrame({"col_a": ["c, d", "e", "g", "e, g", "d, e"]})
all_classes = ["c", "d", "e", "g"]
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(classes=all_classes)

def myfunc(df):
    return pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df["col_a"].values), columns=all_classes)

ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

ddf.map_partitions(myfunc, meta=pd.DataFrame(columns=all_classes)).compute()
```

If the list is not known, then one option is to do a first pass through the dataframe, collecting all unique values, then integrating these classes into a snippet similar to above.